# Multithreaded mex code slower than single threaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, matlab, mex

I am writing mex code in MATLAB to do and operation (because the operation uses a library in c++). The mex code has a section where there is a function that is repeatedly called in a loop with a different argument value, and each function call is independent (i.e., computation of 1 call does not depend on previous calls). So, to speed this up I wrote multithreaded code that creates multiple threads - the exact number of threads is equal to the number of loop iterations, in my example this value is 10. Each thread computes the function in the loop for a separate value of the argument, the threads return and join, some more computation is done and a result is returned.
All this in theory should give me good speedup, but I see that the multithreaded code is a lot slower than the normal single threaded one!! I have access to very powerful 24 core machines, so this is totally baffling, because I'd expected each thread to be scheduled on a separate core.
Any ideas to what is leading to this? Any common problems/errors in code that lead to this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
To answer many doubts raised in solutions proposed by people here, I want to share some information about my code:
1. Each function call takes a few minutes, so synchronization and spawning of threads should not be an overhead here (though if there are any mitigating circumstances in this case, any info about that would be really helpful!)

2. Each thread does access common data structures, arrays, matrices but the values in these are not overwritten at all. All writes to variables are done to variables, pointers, arrays, etc that are local to the thread. So, I am guessing there shouldn't be many cache misses here?
3. Also there are no mutex sections in my code, since no thread write to any common memory location. All writes are to memory locations local to the thread.

I'm still trying to figure out the reason why my multithreaded implementation is not working :( So, any pointers/info will be really helpful!

Thanks!!

Comment: How long does each function call take?  If it's uS and not tens of ms, you're probably wasting your time.  In general, create/join/destroy is just about the worst way to thread stuff off because of the continual overhead and blocking.  Don't ask me why it's on the first page of every thread tutorial book/site as my answer may be offensive to the authors.  Use a pool or some dedicated app-lifetime threads instead.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Try to print some debug lines in the code - for example - "Thread 1 started task 3", "Thread 2 started task 6", ... etc

Comment: Perhaps the C++ library you're using was already multithreaded...

Comment: @angainor - that's why I asked first 'How long does each function call take?'.

Comment: @MartinJames Sure, I overlooked it. It wast just at the begining of your comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how general your question is, the general answer is that there are probably two effects in play:

- There is large overhead involved starting and stopping threads (and synchronizing them), and the computation scaling is not enough to overcome the overhead.  The total times per function call will shed some light on this issue.
- Threads can compete with each other and slow down the aggregate performance.  A common mechanism is "cache thrashing".  Since multiple cores share the same memory controller and parts of the cache hiearchy, one thread can fill the cache with the information it needs, only to have some of that data evicted by the needs of a different thread, causing more trips to main memory.  Since main memory access is so expensive, the end result is a slowdown.

I would test the job with varying numbers of threads.  It may turn out, for instance, that using two threads is advantageous, but four or more is not.  For more detailed answers, add more details to the question, such as type of computation, size of dataset, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't describe what your code does, so this is just guesswork.

Multithreading is not a miracle cure. There are a lot of ways that multithreading what was a single threaded chunk of code can be slower than the original. There's a good deal of overhead involved in spawning, synchronizing, joining, and destroying threads.

Suppose the task at hand was to add ten pairs of numbers. If you make this multithreaded by spawning a thread for each addition and then joining and destroying when the calculation is finished, your multithreaded version will be much, much slower than the original. Threading is not intended for very short duration calculations. The costs of spawning, joining, and destroying are going to overwhelm any speedup you gain by performing those simple tasks in parallel.

Another way to make things slower is to establish barriers the prevent parallel operations. A mutex, for example, to protect against multiple writers simultaneously accessing the same object. That protected code needs to be small. Make the entire bodies of your thread operate under the guise of a mutex and you have the equivalent of a single threaded application that has a whole bunch of threading overhead added in.

Those barriers that preclude parallel execution might be present even if you didn't put them in place. Some of those barriers are in the C standard library. POSIX mandates that most library functions be thread safe. The standard only lists the functions that don't have to be thread safe. If you use library functions in those computations, you might be better of staying single threaded because your code essentially is single threaded.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think your problems are mex specific at all - this sounds like usual performance problems while programing multi-threaded code for SMPs.

To add a little to the already mentioned potential problems:

- [False cache line sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing): you might think that your threads work independently, while in fact they access different data within the same cache line. Trivial example:

  ```
  /* global variable accessible by all threads */
  int thread_data[nthreads];

  /* inside thread function */
  thread_data[thrid] = some_value;
  ```
- inefficient memory bandwidth utilization. On NUMA systems you want the CPUs to access their own data banks. If you do not correctly distribute the data, the CPUs ask for memory from other CPUs. That implies communication, which you do not suspect is there.
- thread affinity. Somewhat connected to the point above. You want your threads to be bound to their own CPUs for the entire duration of the computations. Otherwise they might be migrated by the OS, which causes overhead, and they might be moved further away from the memory bank they will access.